# Prettier Global Ignore VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Every once in a while, whether by accident or out of curiosity, I open up a `*.min.js` file. When I do, every once in a while, either by habit or sadistic pleasure, I hit save, which then causes prettier to unminify the entire file.

This puts me into a "who's on first" routine of hotkeys and VSCode git management to get it to minify again.

Is it possible (maybe using a VSCode extension) to tell prettier to *never touch anything* that matches `*.min.js*`?

Comment: This would also be very useful for `package.json` — I want to auto-format most JSON, and I don't want to add a `.prettierignore` to every little project, with a single line, telling it to ignore `package.json` ...

Comment: related discussion: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/435